# Background task iOS not trigger local notification

Tags: ios, swift, terminate, background-task, localnotification

I have implemented local database and based on some logics I need to scheduled background task and app refresh on every 4 hours. And on app refresh need to generate local notification to show some reminder information.

I created POC and tested with apple xcode command and it generating notification

e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"MyTaskIdentifier"]

but on actual testing I am not getting local notification.

Please let me know if any thing missed or is there any limitation with background schedule job?.
(I read the background task scheduler has some complex algorithm to schedule it and system OS decide it to generate, but for me its was not generate single time)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler

Any help on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the Capabilities and the entries to the plist? If you don't include enough code, we won't have much ability to help you.

Also, if the app is presented notifications don't show up.

Comment: I am using this :https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks.   and following all steps, I have notification logic in same code, and its working as per background demo but notification is not coming.